# Replace leading spaces with asterisk(s)

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace, vscode-snippets

I have two vscode snippets that replace leading four space with `*`.

```
  "Replace leading 4 spaces of non-empty lines with *": {
    "body": [
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([ ]{4})(.+)$/* $2/gm}"
    ],
    "description": "Replace leading 4 spaces of non-empty lines with *"
  },
  "Replace leading 8 spaces of non-empty lines with **": {
    "body": [
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([ ]{8})(.+)$/** $2/gm}"
    ],
    "description": "Replace leading 8 spaces of non-empty lines with **"
  },
```

I want to create a single snippet that will merge both and do the following:

- if there are 4 spaces at the beginning of line, then replace it with single `*`.
- if there are 8 spaces at the beginning of line, then replace it with double `**`.

Sample Input:

```
Motivation's First Law (Law of Persistence):
    A person will remain in their current state of motivation
    In simpler terms, individuals tend to maintain their current

Motivation's Second Law (Law of Momentum):
    The rate of change of motivation of a person is 
    In simpler terms, this law suggests that the greater
```

Sample Output:

```
* Motivation's First Law (Law of Persistence):
** A person will remain in their current state of motivation
** In simpler terms, individuals tend to maintain their current

* Motivation's Second Law (Law of Momentum):
** The rate of change of motivation of a person is
** In simpler terms, this law suggests that the greater
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this keybinding for a snippet (or just use the snippet part) - in your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+w",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([ ]{8})|^([ ]{4})/${1:+** }${2:+* }/gm}"
  },
  "when": "editorHasSelection"
}
```

The order of the regular expression part is important.  It gets any leading 8 spaces into capture group 1.  Or any leading 4 spaces into capture group 2.

Then the transform part `${1:+** }` means **if** there is a group 1 insert `**` .

Likewise, `${2:+* }` means **if** there is a capture group 2 insert `*` .

You will never have both a capture group 1 and 2 in the same match.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is wounderful. `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^( {8})|( {4})/${1:?** :* }/gm}` also works.